# AngularJS - 1 Directive with ng-if statements or two directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Quick question regarding performance in Angular JS.

I have an ng-repeat listing out a load of search results. I use a directive/template to pull out each search item.

Is it better to use an ng-if statement wrapping two directives or to use one directive and have multiple ng-if statements within it, and use expression or statements.

E.G. Ng-if statements wrapping two directives:

```
<div ng-repeat>
    <directive-1 ng-if="this"></directive-1>
    <directive-2 ng-if="that"></directive-2>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat>
   <directive-1></directive-1>
</div>
```

and within directive-1 you have...

```
<img src="1" ng-if="this">
<img src="2" ng-if="that">
<span>{{title || title2}}</span>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

What ng-if is? It is directive (1), with isolated scope (2), that removes or append DOM(3).

What does this mean?

1. Ng-if takes time to initialize.  (not much)
2. Ng-if create new isolated scope. (not much)
3. Ng-if operates with DOM. (possibly very expensive operation)

So, the main problem with preformance connected with DOM. Best way to speed up ng-if - is to reduce dom manipulation.

Also, try to avoid using ng-if with ng-repeat. Of course you can do this, but do this carefully.